# creating table having foreign key that reference another table

Tags: sql, pgadmin

I am using PGAdminIII database.

I have one table named **STOCKREGISTER** which contains composite primary key consisting of three fields ie **stockregisterId,applicationId and date**.

I have to create another table **STOCK** which has a foreignkey field that reference the field **stockregisterId** of **STOCKREGISTER**.If I am trying to create **STOCK** table,an error message is shown.The error message is **"there is no unique contraint matching keys for referenced table STOCKREGISTER"**.What another step I have to take next

this first table

```
CREATE TABLE stock_register
(
  stock_register_id bigint NOT NULL,
  application_id bigserial NOT NULL,
  production_date date NOT NULL,
  opening_bal bigint DEFAULT 0,
  quantity_produced bigint,
  total_quantity bigint 
  CONSTRAINT primarykey PRIMARY KEY (stock_register_id, application_id, production_date),
  CONSTRAINT "foreignKey" FOREIGN KEY (application_id)
      REFERENCES application (application_id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

below is second table.Here I cannot make **stock_register_id** as a foreign key

```
    CREATE TABLE Stock
(
  stock_id bigint NOT NULL,
  stock_register_id bigint,
  dimension bigserial NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT "stockid" PRIMARY KEY (stock_id)
)
```

Comment: Please share both your schemas and code which you tried

Comment: Which version of Sql server is this?

Comment: This is because you cannot make an FK that references one column of a composite PK.  Your FK has to have the same column(s) as the PK (or UK) it references.  The only way to fix your error would be to create a UK (unique key/constraint) on stock_register_id so that your FK has a proper single column key to reference, but then why not simply make stock_register_id the PK of stock_register by itself (i.e. not a composite key)

Answer (score -1):

I guess that syntax should be:

```
CREATE TABLE Stock
(
  stock_id bigint NOT NULL,
  stock_register_id bigint,
  dimension bigserial NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT "stockid"
    FOREIGN KEY (stock_id)
    REFERENCES stock_register (stock_register_id) 
)
```

Comment: an FK must point to a single uniquely identified record in the referenced table, and stock_register_id by itself is not unique according to the composite key

Answer (score -1):

```
CREATE TABLE Stock
(
stock_id bigint NOT NULL,
stock_register_id bigint,
dimension bigserial NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT primaryKey PRIMARY KEY (stock_id),
CONSTRAINT foreignKey FOREIGN KEY(stock_register_id)
REFERENCES stock_register (stock_register_id)
)
```

That should be everything you need. You'll also have to make sure the DB table engines, collations and charsets match up when using Foreign Keys.

For the unique constraint issue, there doesn't seem to be a problem with your `stock_register_id` PK in the `stock_register` table. Based on the name STOCKREGISTER in the error message I suspect it wasn't finding the table `stock_register` in your second Create statement.

Comment: an FK must point to a single uniquely identified record in the referenced table, and stock_register_id by itself is not unique according to the composite key

Answer (score -1):

What is a foreign key?  A pointer to a specific record in another table.

How is a specific record in stock_register identified according to your DDL?  By the unique combination of (stock_register_id, application_id, production_date).

Therefore stock_register_id = 1 could appear on a thousand different records so long as application_id and production_date are different.

Therefore, if all you have is a stock_register_id, there is no way to know which stock_register record it is pointing to and therefore no way for the DBMS to enforce the foreign key.

You must either add application_id and production_date to the stock table and make all three columns together the FK to the composite key on stock_register, or you must remove application_id and production_date from the PK on stock_register so the FK and PK columns match.